# Can the Alert and Notifications service be used with anything other than cf apps?

Tags: notifications, ibm-cloud, alert

Is there any way to use the Alert Notification service with an application running outside of Bluemix?

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question. For questions about the Bluemix service features and capabilities, your best bet is IBM developerWorks Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Bluemix console to create an Alert Notification service instance but do not bind it to  Bluemix application, the console will automatically create a set of service credentials. These can be viewed from within the Bluemix console. They include a URL, name and password. You can copy these into an application running outside of Bluemix.

To manage service credentials outside of the console use the cf service-key commands. The middle command outputs the url, name, password you require:

> cf create-service-key 'IBM Alert Notification-a1' MyKey
>   cf service-key 'IBM Alert Notification-a1' MyKey
>   cf delete-service-key 'IBM Alert Notification-a1' MyKey

Answer (score -1):

Same service is available from IBM Marketplace as well.

You can subscribe to the service here

https://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/alert-notification/us/en-us

Thanks and Regards
Sudhakar